# How I can get video timestamp in yolo v8

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov8

Hello everyone I tried to get timestamp for each detection in video,I tried this but I got an empty list

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from datetime import timedelta
import cv2


model = YOLO('path/yolov8n-cls.pt')
video_path='your video path'
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)




results = model.predict(video_path)  # results list for each frame


for i, frame_result in enumerate(results.xyxy[0]):  # xyxy format contains bounding box coordinates and class probabilities
    timestamp = timedelta(seconds=i /cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))  # calculate timestamp
    print(f"Timestamp: {timestamp}, Probs: {frame_result['probs']}")
```

I tried to set Save=true but nothing happened

Comment: model.predict() returns a list of result objects, and the list itself doesn't have xyxy property. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77448347/16071964

Comment: Use cv2.putText

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69492206/8609909